# MYSQL Query to get the SUM and LAST record value in Group BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

[image]

[image]

I have two table 1 is account and the other one is account_spend_history AS ash account is the parent/master table and the shin a sub table. and has a relationship OneToMany with account(account table id is a foreign key in ash as account_id). please see the image

Now I need to get the account.id, total spend (which is the sum of the amount_spend with same account_id) and last spend (is the last record inserted in ash table against and account_id i.e. amount_spend value corresponding with MAX(ash.id)), that is

```
id  |  spend_total  |  last_spend
---------------------------------
1   |  30           |   18
2   |  280          |   120
3   |  20           |   20
```

```
SELECT a.id, SUM(ash.amount_spend) AS spend_total
FROM accounts as a
INNER JOIN account_spend_history AS ash ON ash.account_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Im getting the account.id and sum of ash.amount spend, but I also need last spend. How to get that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using a `correlated subquery`:

```
SELECT a.id, SUM(ash.amount_spend) AS spend_total,
       (SELECT amount_spend 
        FROM account_spend_history as ash2 
        WHERE ash2.account_id = a.id 
        ORDER BY ash2.id DESC LIMIT 1) as last_spend
FROM accounts as a
    INNER JOIN account_spend_history AS ash ON ash.account_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: Thanks @sgeddes, it is working for me, and i got the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `MAX(ash.id)` as well in your query and then use it to join back to `account_spend_history` table:

```
SELECT id, spend_total, amount_send as last_spend
FROM (
  SELECT a.id, SUM(ash.amount_spend) AS spend_total, MAX(ash.id) AS ash_id
  FROM accounts as a
  INNER JOIN account_spend_history AS ash ON ash.account_id = a.id
  GROUP BY a.id) AS t1
INNER JOIN account_spend_history AS ash ON ash.id = t1.ash_id
```

Comment: Hi @Giorgos Betsos, thanks for helping me. I write the query but i got an error.

**#1054 - Unknown column 'amount_send' in 'field list' .**

SELECT t1.id,
       spend_total,
       amount_send AS last_spend
FROM
  (SELECT a.id,
           SUM(ash.amount_spend) AS spend_total,
           MAX(ash.id) AS ash_id
   FROM accounts AS a
   INNER JOIN account_spend_history AS ash ON ash.account_id = a.id
   GROUP BY a.id
   ) AS t1
INNER JOIN account_spend_history AS ash ON ash.id = t1.ash_id

Answer (score 0):

You can use a in clause and subquery

```
SELECT a.id, SUM(ash.amount_spend) AS spend_total, x.last_spend 
FROM accounts as a
INNER JOIN account_spend_history AS ash ON ash.account_id = a.id
INNER JOIN  ( 
  select account_id, last_spend, start_date 
  from account_spend_history
  where (start_date, acoount_id) in  ( 
      select  max(start_date), account_id 
      from account_spend_history 
      group by account_id 
    ) 
) x on x.id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
```